# Magento 1 : Get product collection using command line throwing error

Tags: product, error, catalog, command-line, command

I have a script file like getproducts.php & have placed it under script/getproducts.php. I want to get products collection in my script file.

code in my file:

```
<?php

require_once('../app/Mage.php'); 

umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');

Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

echo "Product Count ".$productCollection->getSize();
```

After executing my getproducts.php through command line

```
html/demosite/script$ php getproducts.php
```

I am getting error on prompt:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid entity_type specified: catalog_product' in /var/www/html/demosite/app/Mage.php:595
```

Note : However it's working when trying to hit directly by Url: `http://localhost/demosite/script/getproducts.php`

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();


ini_set("memory_limit","1024M");
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

echo "Product Count ".$productCollection->getSize();
```

Comment: Tried. It's not working. same issue.